# No goals have been specified for this build.

Tags: maven, docker

I'm trying to run Maven in Docker.

So I pulled the image from her https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/.

```
docker pull maven
```

However, when I run it:

```
docker run maven
```

I get:

```
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

I don't have experience with Maven so I don't understand what's causing this issue.

The Docker container only has Maven installed, but it's not running it so I don't understand how Maven can throw an error.

Comment: You need to define if you like to run the life cycle via `package` or `deploy` etc. or run a goal of a plugin like `surefire:test` etc.

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly should be changed in the code?

Comment: You need to do: ` docher run maven clean` ? Check if this will without any issue...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `clean install` in Goal tab after you click `build as maven`.